# New Flutter Project wizard not showing on Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: dart, flutter, android-studio-3.0

I installed Flutter following official document and also installed Flutter and Dart plugin on Android Studio.

But, I can't see File>New Flutter Project wizard on Android Studio 3.0.1

I run "flutter doctor" command. See the below output.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.1.5, on Mac OS X 10.13.3 17D102, locale en-TR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.3.3)
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Did you restart AS after plugin install?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer millions of time. I can create Flutter application on Intellj CE.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: No, I can't. I continue to use Intellj CE not Android Studio.

Comment: @abalta did you solve this?

Comment: no, I didn't @rya, I decided to use Intellj CE instead of AS

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Had the same problem. Check-in Android Studio if the Dart and Flutter plugins are both installed and marked with a lock symbol in Preferences --> Plugins.

Anyway, the following procedure helped me:

1. uninstall the Flutter plugin
2. restart Android Studio.
3. uninstall the Dart plugin
4. restart Android Studio again which seemed important to do
5. install the Dart plugin again
6. restart Android Studio although it is annoying
7. install the Flutter plugin again
8. and guess: restart Android Studio

After the last restart I saw the success message:

[image: success notification of flutter]

I assume we both installed both plugins without restarting after Dart.

Comment: The issue presented itself for me after a studio update. This fix worked for me. Need to do all the steps exactly in that order. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like Mumbo jumbo to me. No results.

Comment: it shows me this dialog "welcome to flutter", but even though their no option came up for "start new flutter projects" .

Comment: Don't need to do all of this: Simply install flutter plugin: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor

Comment: Poor solution. uzay95 answer should be accepted. That's the way to go.

Comment: In my case I had flutter plugin installed, but I had not the dart plugin. After installing it and restarting the android studio the option to create a flutter project appeared.

Comment: In my case flutter and dart was not installed, thanks

Answer (score 180):

You need check the “AndroidAPK Support” in your Plugins.

See this screenshot:
[image: Android APK Support must be ticked in "Plugins"]

Comment: this was the issue for me !

Comment: this fixed the issue in my case

Comment: I had this Android APK Support unchecked. Worked like a charm. Also, check if you've disabled git or version plugins.

Comment: This worked for me! I'm using the web output so I disabled these to help IDE performance. Not sure why they are required to use the Create Wizard but there we go. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @mayi. Enabling Both android APK support and Android NDK Support  work like a charm.

Comment: Thanks. Just searched for Android APK Support in Preferences and it was unchecked, so I checked it and applied changes and restarted the IDE. And that's it!

Comment: This worked like a charm, can you explain how did you reach to this solution?

Answer (score 65):

If you are sure to have both Dart and Flutter plugins correctly installed, check again your Plugins and **be sure that Android APK Support is enabled**.

If it isn't, enable it!

[image: Android APK Support]

Et voilà! Now everything should be fine:

[image: New Flutter project]

You can find the plugin menu inside the Welcome page
[image: Plugin from Welcome page]

or, when you have a project opened, inside the Preferences menu:
[image: Plugin menu inside Preferences menu]

Comment: thanks. after above step restart ide, then similarly search for flutter install and restart again.

Answer (score 46):

I also faced it but soon I solved it

I simply install **flutter** and **dart** plugins and restarted Android Studio.

After restarting I noticed that there is no Wizard for creating flutter apps. But soon I realized that I have disabled some plugins ( Android Studio's default plugins ) so I enabled all plugins and restarted Android Studio again and BOOM! Now there is a wizard for Creating Flutter Apps.

Hope this helps you !

Comment: This was the same for me, the specific plugin was Android APK Support

Comment: Thank you ! After trying uninstalling restarting many times and got failed. Until use your suggestion, it works!!!

Comment: This is the real answer, though APK, NPK, seemed to be the 2 i needed to get it working.

Comment: Simply install flutter plugin: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor

Comment: for the newest android studio version: Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2
this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 38):

My answer will be nearly same with @VickyBOSS but I'll upload screenshots of before and after ;)

First and foremost **Flutter** and **Dart plugins** must be installed before.
[image]

After installing these plugins you can check if it is ok or not with `flutter doctor`
[image]

If you hadn't installed the plugins you would have this:
[image]

**Android Studio**
At first, I didn't see "Start a new Flutter project" 
[image]
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: after enabling "Andorid APK Support" and "Andorid NDK Support"  worked me

Comment: Thanks buddy , only android apk support worked for me .

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, This worked for me after a couple of attempts, Unfortunately, flutter documentation isn't helpful on this issue, they need address this.

Answer (score 14):

I have also same problem.but what can you do in that situation is Just create the project with command line :

> flutter  create  your_app_name

Now open android studio and open that project. Hope this works well

Comment: where we use this command ....command prompt or terminal of android studio?

Answer (score 11):

1. Yes first update all your plugins related to flutter and dart .
2. "AndroidAPK Support" plugin(install /enable /update).

3.This will work for all the AS , checked this on AS 3.4 also .

4. Thanks to the guys who answered before me .

Answer (score 9):

I also ran into this issue and the steps above didn't work. What I did was check which plugins I have enabled and realized that `Android APK Support` and `Android NDK Support` was disabled in my AS. After enabling this and restarting android studio everything seems to be working correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Got the same problem, fixed it by installing dart first using the plugin manager of android studio. Then install flutter plugin.

Comment: This is the real answer to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me. 
Install Dart and Flutter manually from Plugins:

- Open Plugins (For Mac: Configure -> Plugins OR Android Studio -> Preferences -> Plugins)
- Search for Dart -> Search in repositories -> Install -> Restart Android studio
- Search for Flutter -> Search in repositories -> Install -> Restart Android Studio

Comment: Thanks this is what worked for me. :) In my case, just downloading the patch file and having updated to android studio 3.1.2 does not show start a new flutter project by default.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Do this]
Just Restore your IDE settings as shown in image

File -> Manage Ide Settings -> **Restore default settings**

This will remove your installed plugins and ask you again to install them.

Comment: That crashed my Android Studio, i couldn't open it again, long list of errors...  i had to reinstall it

Answer (score 3):

How to set flutter wizard in Android Studio 3.0

1. File > Close Project
2. Configure > Check for Updates
3. You will find Flutter and Dart updates. Update and Restart. Downloading Patch.
4. File > New Flutter Project or Select new Flutter Project.

Hope your problem resolved.
Happy Codings!!

Answer (score 3):

It was little different in my case. After upgrading to newest release of Android studio. The dart flutter and other related plugins were in incompatible mode.
You can check that by going to Android Studio=> Plugins.

I simply update those plugins and then restart the IDE and it works fine.
[image: Android studio 4. Plugin update window.]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue sometime ago even after installing both Dart and Flutter plugins for intelliJ, I fixed it like this...

STEP ONE: Click "Repair IDE"

[image: step one]

STEP TWO: Click "Rescan Project Indexes" at the bottom

[image: step two]

STEP THREE: Click "Reopen Project" at the bottom
[image: step three]

Answer (score 2):

Update flutter using below command

> flutter upgrade

and again create flutter application from android studio

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, Flutter refused to show New `Flutter Project` in android studio 3.1

but when I use android studio 3.2 it works fine after installing Dart and flutter plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have flutter and dart installed, then enable Android apk support; this helped me

Answer (score 2):

Well go to command line and check flutter doctor , if all good give command to your project directory

flutter create appname

and import this to androidstudio , this will generate necessary plugins.

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstall Flutter and Dart plugin
2. Restart Android Studio
3. Install Flutter Plugin (it will prompt you to install Dart plugin as well. Accept it)
4. Restart Android Studio

Also, reminder to check whether the plugin is enabled or not. Go to Preferences -> Plugins -> Flutter/Dart. Although, it's enabled by default, you may have had to disable it at some point in the past. In that case, just enable it from Preferences -> Plugin -> Flutter/Dart if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I did not have APK/NDK support Plugin, added that and it worked. Of course restart IDE couple of times.

Comment: I did not need to enable NDK support plugin (only APK support) to see the entry appear. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and finally sorted out. It's usually caused by your upgrade of Android Studio from 2.x to 3.x at the same time.

In short, it's because Flutter is not correctly configurated, but behind the scene there might be different reasons, so the universal solution is to run **`flutter doctor -v`** to diagnose and see what's missing.

[First make sure you've already followed the setup steps in Flutter's official documentation and have your Android SDK updated.]

In my own case, a couple of things to fix:

1. Update the JAVA_HOME path in `.bash_profile`. Because I have 2 Java versions installed and so I updated it to use the same as Android Studio does. This is critical as `flutter doctor` relies on Java to check some of your configurations.
2. `Some Android licenses not accepted` - follow flutter doctor's advice to accept all licenses.
3. Android Studio's Flutter plugin version too low - simply update it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have done everything here,it may not work if you have Android Studio 4.x or canary
It works only in lower version

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only miss Dart plugin so i installed and on IDE restart it was there

Answer (score -1):

just make sure you enable the Android Apk Support and its will work for sure