# Flutter installed on Windows 10, Android 3.6.3 but not showing create new Flutter project though installed as per doc

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

Am trying to install the flutter as per https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows. All steps have done properly, but still cant find the create new flutter project in the welcome screen.please, find the attached screenshot and help me on this

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you restart android studio?

Comment: Hi Sandeep, yes i did multiple times but still the same screen

Comment: I think this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405321/new-flutter-project-wizard-not-showing-on-android-studio-3-0-1

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, This worked for me after a couple of attempts, Unfortunately, flutter documentation isn't helpful on this issue, they need address this.