# Start New Flutter Project wizard not showing on Android Studio 3.6.3

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using Android Studio 3.6.3, the latest version. After installing Flutter plugin, it's showing nothing on the face to start a project.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
```

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
    ✗ Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.

Comment: Did you restart IDE?

Comment: yes, and tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405321/new-flutter-project-wizard-not-showing-on-android-studio-3-0-1 this also, that the only answer in stack owerflow

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#install-android-studio here flutter notes an issue. But the solution not working.

Comment: Thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60577338/9558020 worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Do some steps to overcome this problem:

- Open Android Studio
- Go to **File** => **Settings..**
- Select **Plugins** menu from left panel
- Type ***flutter*** on search box [ If you not installed Flutter plugin
  before, please install and restart IDE ]
- Or
- Select **Installed** tab [ If **Marketplace** tab is selected then Flutter would
  not have any Update or Uninstall option ]
- Then Update Flutter plugin and restart IDE

[image]

**Note**: If you have any Uninstall option for Flutter plugin then uninstall first. Install and restart IDE.

[image]

Hopefully your problem will be solved. Thanks