# New Flutter Project wizard not showing on Android Studio 4.0.1

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Since the Android Studio 4 got released, the startup dialog is missing the option to create a new flutter project. I've tried all of the solutions mentioned here

[New Flutter Project wizard not showing on Android Studio 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405321/new-flutter-project-wizard-not-showing-on-android-studio-3-0-1)

But still no luck! What to do? Does anybody has this even working with AS 4.0.1??

[image]

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.20.0-7.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.388], locale en-US)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Are the Flutter + dart plugins installed ? Update them if necessary

Comment: @dev-aentgs yes, both plugins are updated and I tried Uninstall/install them too.. didn't work.. all studio default plugins are enabled too.

Comment: oh ok. Restart your system once. What is the version number of flutter plugin?

Comment: 47.1.2 this is the version number @dev-aentgs  for flutter plugin

Comment: I have the same version. It works on Android Studio 4.0.1. Restart your system once. If it still doesn't show up add `flutter doctor` output.

Comment: restarted system, still no luck @dev-aentgs ... added flutter doctor summary too. please have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218820/discussion-between-dev-aentgs-and-teekam-suthar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Okay,

finally fixed this by removing `.AndroidStudio4.0` config folder from my user directory.

It simply created a new `.AndroidStudio4.0` folder along with the next launch of Android Studio, installed dart and flutter plugins and I'm good to go.

```
 - close Android Studio if it's running.
 - delete or rename the `.AndroidStudio4.0` config folder in user directory.
 - launch Android Studio, and walk through a new configuration 
 - install `dart` and `flutter` plugins and restart IDE
```

Now you should probably see the option in launch wizard.

update:
`In new version of Android Studio(from ~4.1), they have moved the location of config folder. You can find it here: C:\Users\%userfolder%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1`

[image]

Comment: thanks, @Teekam, I just rename AndroidStudio4.0  from c/:user/your_name/AndroidStudio4.0 . then run android studio.  everything looks good

Comment: glad to hear it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the AndoidStudio4.0 config folder in user directory.
Launch android studio
Do all the required configuration settings
Install Flutter and Dart
Restart your IDE

All should be well

Comment: don't you think it is the same answer as above?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had just installed Flutter and Dart plugin. I did not had AndroidStudio4.0 folder. My Android Studio version: 4.1

Comment: In new version of Android Studio, they have moved the location of config folder. You can find it here: `C:\Users\%userfolder%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1`

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answer above, but none worked for me.
By enabling the **Android APK Support** & **Android NDK Support** plugins and restarting Android studio, the option to create a flutter project started showing.
By the way I use Android studio v4.0.1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution..
Install plugins for flutter and Dart and then restart the Android studio.. It will work.